# Error java.util.Date

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm Trying to Convert String to Date in My Android App to Insert Data in SQL Database through jdbc. But while i tried to convert String to Date i'm Getting the Following Error.

```
10-29 15:34:55.404: W/Error connection(11433): java.util.Date
```

Here is My Sample Code Here i imported java.util.Date;

```
String sDate="29/10/2012 12:00:00 AM";
Date bondDate = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate);
CallableStatement cStmtInsertPOdetails =conn.prepareCall("{call dbo.InsertDetails(?)}");
cStmtInsertPOdetails.setDate("@POD_BondDate",(java.sql.Date)bondDate);
```

Please Help me To Solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bondDate` which is [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) can not be cast to [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). Use `new java.sql.Date(bondDate.getTime())`

```
    String sDate = "29/10/2012 12:00:00 AM";
    Date bondDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(bondDate.getTime());
```

Though it will be advisable to use pattern `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a`. Check [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to understand about `Time Pattern Syntax`

Comment: java.sql.Date cDate= new java.sql.Date(bondDate .getDate()); This Code is Working Fine But It's Giving me wrong output 1970-01-01

Comment: Its not `getDate()` its `getTime()` Check the answer correctly

Comment: No.`getTime() `returns you`miliseconds for current date` which is passed to `java.sq.Date(long miliseconds)` which will then return you the `correct date`.

Answer (score 0):

Your date pattern does not match with date string. Pattern would be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a`.

```
String sDate="29/10/2012 12:00:00 AM";
Date bondDate = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a").parse(sDate);
```

Comment: Yes it looses the time but it will never generate error unless strict mode is on. Any way removing negative vote. You need to edit the answer my vote is locked.